# Downloading MP4 files with PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, video, mp4

I am trying to download a video from one of my servers to another of my servers. I was using CURL because copy() did not download the audio from the video. However, CURL downloaded corrupted files (?) and do not. This is how I'm downloading the MP4 file right now:

```
$source = "https://link.com/video.mp4";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "video/video.mp4";
$file = fopen($destination, "wb");
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Is there anything special for MP4 files to download properly?

`array(26) { ["url"]=> string(60) "https://link.com/video.mp4" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(1) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.135745) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(8.4E-5) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.056009) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(13) "AN-IP :D" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(443) ["local_ip"]=> string(11) "192.168.0.9" ["local_port"]=> int(57478) }`

Comment: You are not really checking if the transfer performed successfully, you call `curl_error()` but you are not checking the value returned by that function (you can also use [`curl_errorno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)).

Comment: Perfect snippet, it works great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must open the file in binary mode to ensure file is saved to disk correctly.

```
$file = fopen($destination, "wb");
```

Also use `fwrite` instead of fputs

```
fwrite($file, $data);
```

Check that `video.mp4` downloads from the browser correctly. Maybe it is redirecting? If so the add this option.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

If is still does not work then dump out this info and post it.

```
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

Comment: Still the same. This is what I get when trying to open the video: `QuickTime Player can't open “video.mp4”.` and it says it has 0 bytes

Comment: I will update my question with what I have. It's doing the same thing as before

Comment: Stupid question: Do you have proper permissions for the Apache user to write to the specified $destination directory?

Comment: @GeorgeQ I updated my question with what I get. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` did not work

Comment: @JacquesAmar I have 755 permission on the folder. EDIT: Just tried it with 777 and still nothing

Comment: You could also try taking out the ssl version line

Comment: @GeorgeQ You are amazing. Thank you :D